# Maintain Added List Item while binding from datasource

Tags: asp.net, datasource, asp.net-controls

I have a drop down list, and I added some items in it as follows

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInsAuther" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceInsAuthers" DataTextField="AutherName" 
            DataValueField="AutherID">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">No Authers</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And in Datasource

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceInsAuthers" runat="server" 
            SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="MyProject.BusinessLayer.AuthersFactory">
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When it loads it clears the list and loads the new items, I don't want to make a custom binder on page load, how can I maintain my added items in the list while binding from datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` to the DropDownList.  Be aware though, if you bind multiple times it will keep adding the items over and over.  You would get around this by putting the call to `DataBind()` in a if `(!IsPostBak)` but I am not sure if you can do this with an ObjectDataSource.